# Пропадает первая строка в списках

Tags: php

Не могу понять, почему при выводе таблицы пропадает первая строка. То есть есть список, где допустим: иванов, петров, сидоров. А выводится всё начиная с петрова.

```
<?php

    $myCmd = "SELECT * FROM dlpodrazdeleniya, dldoctor, dlSpec, dltime WHERE id='$cat' AND dldoctor.idPodr = dlpodrazdeleniya.idPodr AND dldoctor.SpecID =  dlSpec.SpecID AND dldoctor.DoctorID =  dltime.DoctorID";
    $buf = mysql_query($myCmd);

  echo "<table  class='sortable1' id='table'>\n";
                echo "<tr align='center'>\n";
                if (!empty($buf['Ychastok'])) {
                echo "<th>Участок</th>\n";
                }
                if (!empty($buf['Cabinet'])) {
                echo "<th>Кабинет</th>\n";
            }
                echo "<th>ФИО врача</th>\n";
                echo "<th>Специалист</th>\n";
                echo "</tr>\n";

    for($i=1; $i<=mysql_num_rows($buf); $i++) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($buf);

                echo "<tr align='center'>\n";
                if (!empty($row['Ychastok'])) {
                echo "<td><font color=red>".$row['Ychastok']."</td>\n";
                }

                if (!empty($row['Cabinet'])) {
                echo "<td><font color=red>".$row['Cabinet']."</td>\n";
                }
                echo "<td><font color=red>".$row['LastName']." ".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['MiddleName']."</td>\n";
                echo "<td><font color=red>".$row['SpecName']."</font color></td>\n";
                echo "</tr>\n";

        }               
     echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Счет начинается с 0, а не с 1:

```
for($i=0; $i<=mysql_num_rows($buf); $i++)
```